# Is there a way to index personal data both local and cloud?

Tags: search-engine

I am looking for a way to index all my data, be it local or remote, so that I can find my own stuff easily, it can be a library, an API, or a software package, so that all my blog posts, tweets, emails and facebook updates etc can be searchable securely for my own purposes.

Is this possible already?

Comment: Have a look on [Apache Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/). This is a mature open source information retrieval library that will do most of the dirty work for you.

Answer (score 2):

I have found this wonderful tool: http://www.yacy.net/en/index.html

> Web Search by the people, for the people
>
> YaCy is a free search engine that anyone can use to build a search
>   portal for their intranet or to help search the public internet. When
>   contributing to the world-wide peer network, the scale of YaCy is
>   limited only by the number of users in the world and can index
>   billions of web pages. It is fully decentralized, all users of the
>   search engine network are equal, the network does not store user
>   search requests and it is not possible for anyone to censor the
>   content of the shared index. We want to achieve freedom of information
>   through a free, distributed web search which is powered by the world's
>   users.